# how to pass album object from javascript to php

Tags: php, sdk

I am trying to fetch photo albums from facebook to my website, I used javascript to connect to facebook API, As you know facebook sends object named "response" which gives me album details, I want to pass this object to my index.php page to read its content their.

could you please tell me how to pass and read this opject

Comment: you can pass this object by sending a web request to the server. for example, using AJAX from the web page.

Comment: can you please give a code sample to do so